# Point conversion and scaling in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Our UI designer provides us the designs with the dimensions in points on a iPhone XS device. Please advice on the following;

- How can these dimensions be converted to points in Xamarin?
- How to Scale down (eg : font sizes) to small screens (eg: iPhone SE)?

Comment: 1. Choose a [layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/) you want to use and created those views in the page with specific size. 2. If you are asking which font size you have to use in iPhone SE, I would recommend you ask your UI designer about this question. What the UI designer want is what you have to do. If you are asking the width/height of views in small screens, I think you can set a ratio in different screen size. That's also depending on the UI designer.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT 1. So how can the 'specific size' be determined. For an instance if the margin from top is defined as 10pt in the design what amount should be specified in the XAML as the margin?

Comment: That's depending on which layout you use, for example if you use [absolute-layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout), you can set AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds directly. Read the document first.

Comment: There is also an example under each layout and you can have a look: [exploring-a-complex-layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout#exploring-a-complex-layout)

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT No the issue is not about setting the margin but about identifying the amount that should be specified. So in the design if the margin is 10pt and we set the exact amount as the margin in the XAML then when the screen is rendered that won't look exactly as the design. Hope I'm clear enough here.

Comment: I can't agree with what you said that if you set a margin to 10pt then the margin you see on the screen does't not equal to 10pt.

Comment: The question is does the points in iOS is equal to the points in Xamarin Forms. If not how to do the conversion?

Comment: Depending on the device, there may be 1, 2, or 3 pixels to the point.

Comment: So if the design (given by the UI designer) is provided for a iPhone XS device which is having 3 pixels per point, is it safe to multiply the amount by 3 to get the corresponding Xamarin points? Say if the margin in design is 10pt does it map to 30pt in the XAML?

Comment: Sorry,I'm not sure right now, you can have a  try on the different screen with different size to see the result.